# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser with Java Applet. onchange event is not fired if select value from pop up using mouse

Tags: c#, .net

I am using custom implementation of System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser (say ExtendedBrowser) in my application.http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx

I am loading an applet on this ExtendedBrowser. However problem is the `onchange` event is not fired if a value is selected from the pop up using a mouse. All the other controls are working fine.

This problem doesn't occur with IE or FF, but only on the WebBrowser control. 
Any Idea what might be stopping event from being triggered.

Comment: If the value is changed via keyboard does the OnChange fire?

Comment: onchange isn't fired when selecting a value within the Java applet?

Comment: If the value is changed via keyboard, event of comboBox gets fired but not when selected using mouse. I observed that event are going to panel below the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=386774). Need to call `this.DefWndProc(ref m)` instead of `base.WndProc(ref m)` for `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`